# How can we further troubleshoot these random app pool crashes in IIS

Tags: .net, iis

We are experiencing some random app pool crashes on one of our production servers. We are using IIS version 8.

I've put in place additional logging and analysed it through DebugDiag. The summary output from that is:

In w3wp.exe.11696.dmp the assembly instruction at clr!Assembly::GetSecurityDescriptor+1a in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000040 on thread 9

I need help to know how if there's anything further we can do to troubleshoot this and to prevent these crashes from happening.

Comment: A crash like that requires lots of efforts to troubleshoot, so you’d better open a support ticket with Microsoft or hire an experienced consultant. A place like this won’t help much.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks both for your responses. I did understand that no-one would be likely to solve the problem based on that logging info, so I appreciate the suggestions for next steps. I'll raise a support ticket with Microsoft and see where that takes me.